# GroupFooterBand doesn't grow with sumSum() in DevExpress Reports

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I make report with DevExpress Reports. The data in the table is grouped by one of the fields. GroupFooter displays fields with the sum of values in a data group. One of the fields has a different height depending on the data and all fields in the row change their height according to the Can grow property. In GroupFooter, the Summary = Group option is selected for the fields. But when I add sumSum() to the Expression Editor for field to display the sum of the group values, the height of the field grows, but the height of GroupFooterBand does not. Because of this, the field text overlaps other fields. How to use sumSum() so that GroupFooterBand can grow?
With this code GroupFooterBand is growing:

```
Iif([departmentcost_211] != 0, '211:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_211], 2) + NewLine(), null) +
Iif([departmentcost_212] != 0, '212:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_212], 2) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif([departmentcost_213] != 0, '213:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_213], 2) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif([departmentcost_221] != 0, '221:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_221], 2) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif([departmentcost_222] != 0, '222:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_222], 2) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif([departmentcost_223] != 0, '223:' + NewLine() + Round([departmentcost_223], 2) + NewLine(), null)
```

But with this code GroupFooterBand does not growing:

```
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_211]) != 0, '211:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_211], 2)) + NewLine(), null) +
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_212]) != 0, '212:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_212], 2)) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_213]) != 0, '213:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_213], 2)) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_221]) != 0, '221:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_221], 2)) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_222]) != 0, '222:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_222], 2)) + NewLine(), null) + 
Iif(sumSum([departmentcost_223]) != 0, '223:' + NewLine() + sumSum(Round([departmentcost_223], 2)) + NewLine(), null)
```